# SVG won't Align in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, alignment

Can't seem to figure out why SVGs won't properly align in Illustrator.

I'm aligning to artboard and for whatever reason the object refuses to align properly.

Here's it aligned  horizontally.

Any ideas?  Other objects works just fine.

[image]

Comment: What's the expected result? Where should it be aligned to? Do you see the problem in Illustrator or when viewing the file somewhere else?

Comment: @Luciano i added a screenshot above that shows what happens when I horizontally align the object. The object appear at the bottom and not in the middle horizontally. Issues is in illustrator as well.

Comment: @Peekay Tip for the future, please input any screenshots/images of your work/question-related graphics so we don't have to click on external links for reference. Thank you!

Comment: Sometimes an invisible object in a group or clip group may be the culprit of weird alignment issues. Use ctrl+y to see the outlines of all objects to see if there's nothing hiding from you.

Comment: @PieBie thanks,  took a look at the layers panel and there was some weird stuff going on.  Got it to work.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be caused by two possibilities:

There is a bounding box surrounding the SVG.  Simulated example with the below image:

[image]

Pay close attention to the blue box surrounding the pink star.  If that is the case you need to modify the SVG and get rid of the bounding box so this would require some editing on the SVG.

Other possibility is you do no have your `Align To` options set correctly in the `Align` Panel:

[image]

To adjust these settings you can go to `Window -> Align -> Align To`

Answer (score 0):

Solution,
Don't drag and drop the SVG in the Ai rather open it in a new window of Ai and then copy and paste the SVG in your working artboard, hopefully, it will work. It is working for me this way.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all clipping masks.
Select->Object->Clipping Mask. Edit->Clear - or Alt Ctrl 7